# Encoding a file path as query parameter with Retrofit2 doesn't work

Tags: java, retrofit2, url-encoding

I'm trying to encode a file path in a query parameter, but I have always the same output.
I've tried:
`@Query(value="path", encoded=false) String path`
and

```
@Query(value="path", encoded=true) String path
```

but the request looks like this in both cases:

```
/myendpoint?path=C:\Development\some\random\filepath
```

I expect the following output:

```
/myendpoint?path=file:%5C%5C%5CC:%5CDevelopment%5Csome%5Crandom%5Cfilepath
```

if this is not possible it would be nice to get this output:

```
/myendpoint?path=C:%5CDevelopment%5Csome%5Crandom%5Cfilepath
```

so I can add the "file:\\" string to the file path before passing it to my retrofit method, but the Url-encoding should be done by retrofit and the path should be sent as query parameter!
Do anybody know how to get this work?

**Edit:**
As I found out Retrofit has the following behaviour for query-encoding:

- if the query contains invalid characters (not encoded, yet) encoding doesn't work
- if the query contains valid characters (already encoded) encoding works (encoded parameter turns encoding on and off)

Thank you

Comment: `@Query("path")` (false) should have worked - as documented. Is the backslash you see, indeed a backslash? Often browsers will show links url decoded, so instead of `%5C` in the link simply `\ `.

Comment: Yes, it is I've traced that with fiddler and there is no difference.
I'm not sure if this is a bug because the encoding works every time as expected if it is unnecessary because all characters are valid already.
If I use URL-Encoding I do so if the characters are not valid to avoid crashes in backend what is clearly not possible with this configuration.
As a more generic workaround, I use a URI path now which solves the problem for me but the query encoding of retrofit seems to be quite useless at the moment or do I miss something in there?